# Firebase Swift Classes/Protocols/Extensions to help creating model objects based on database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

does something more or less ready-made exist (e.g. a Protocol which a class has to conform with which inits with a FIRDataSnapshot?) supporting in creating models based on Firebase Snapshots? Maybe even including nested keys?

It must make totally sense to have something like this to avoid unstructured programming, right?